# Найти дочерний элемент в теле первого дочернего элемента в Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть DOM:

```
<div class="col_gauche2_result_datasheet">
    <div class="bloc_detail">
        <table class="table_detail_profil"><tbody></tbody></table>
    </div>
    <div class="bloc_detail">...</div>
    <div class="bloc_detail">...</div>
    <div class="bloc_detail">...</div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно обратиться к блоку с классом `.col_gauche2_result_datasheet`, затем к его **первому** дочернему элементу с классом `.bloc_detail` и вытащить из него содержимое тела таблицы. Для этого я обратился к функции `select()` в Beautiful Soup:

```
soup.find('div', {'class': 'col_gauche2_result_datasheet'}).select('.bloc_detail:first-of-type').find('table', {'class': 'table_detail_profil'}).find('tbody')
```

Но, почему-то получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Как это исправить?

Comment: Можно добавить `[0]` после `.select()`. Или (вроде) можно обойтись одним `select`: `soup.select('.col_gauche2_result_datasheet .bloc_detail:first-of-type table.table_detail_profil tbody')[0]`

Comment: @diraria добавил индекс после `select()` - `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Кажется проблема в `first-of-type`. Можно убрать его и написать так: `soup.select_one('.col_gauche2_result_datasheet .bloc_detail').select_one('table.table_detail_profil tbody')`. Это работает на
 [Ideone](https://ideone.com/VSaZwk)

Comment: @diraria странно, а у меня почему-то возвращается `None`.

Comment: Значит в переменной `soup` находится что-то не то. Попробуй вывести её и её тип (`type(soup)`)

Comment: @diraria `type(soup)` = `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
`. Вывод самого soup выводит html запрашиваемой мной страницы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65719/discussion-between-diraria-and-jamesjgoodwin).

Answer (score 1):

Задача решилась. Проблема заключалась в том, что если в таблице нет `<tbody>`, то браузер сам добавлял его в таблицу. А BeaitufilSoup парсил html без tbody. Потому-то селектор `.select_one('table.table_detail_profil tbody')` ничего не находил и выводил `NoneType`. Спасибо [@diraria](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227016/diraria) за подсказку.